# Python 3.x: alternative pprint implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pprint

Standard [`pprint`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/pprint.html) module is nice when deals with lists, dicts and so on. But sometimes completely unusable with custom classes:

- The only way to make it print usable information about an object of some class is to override `__repr__`, but what if my class already have nice, `eval()`'able `__repr__` which is not showing the information I want to see in pprint ouput?
- Ok, I will write print-oriented `__repr__`, but in this case it is impossible to pretty-print something inside my class:

.

```
class Data:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = {...}
```

I can't pretty-print `self.d` contents, I can return one-line representation only(at least without playing with stacktraces, etc).
 - Overriding `PrettyPrinter` is not an option, I dont want to do it every time I want to pretty-print the same class.

So... Is there any alternatives to pprint which allows to make a custom class pretty-printable?

Comment: Found https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pretty/0.1 , but it seems to be py2.X only

Comment: "I can return one-line representation only" -- why is this? NumPy for example returns multi-line repr()s that work just fine. Here's an example, as a Python string : `"array([(0, 0, (0, 0, 0)), (0, 0, (0, 0, 0)), (0, 0, (0, 0, 0)),\n       (0, 0, (0, 0, 0))], \n      dtype=[('foo', 'u1'), ('bar', '<u2'), ('baz', [('fbb', 'u1'), ('oaa', 'u1'), ('orz', 'u1')])])"` . It eval()'s fine, with 'array' in the namespace.

Comment: @kampu I meant I cant return multiline string because it will break `pprint` indentation.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to edit and indicate I'd just realized that, but the 5min grace period on editing had run out. Good to know we're on the same page, anyway :)

Comment: @Equidamoid, if you need a Python 3 solution, please indicate it in your question, and add an appropriate tag.

Comment: And why is subclassing `PrettyPrinter` not an option?

Comment: And why is it impossible to pretty-print something inside your class in case of writing a custom `__repr__`? The string it returns can contain a representation of any field of your object.

Comment: @utapyngo done. Oops, the phrase about subclassing is incorrect a little bit %) I just don't want to add support for the particular class to `PrettyPrinter` (because class-specific code shouldn't be there), and looking for "generic" solution, such as the one mentioned in my 1st comment.

Comment: @utapyngo it is impossible to generate proper multiline string in `__repr__` because of unknown current indentation level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an improved and maintained Python 2.x/3.x port of "pretty" library in IPython: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.lib.pretty.html

Answer (score 3):

If [the pretty module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pretty/0.1) satisfies your needs, you can make it work with Python 3.

1. [Download](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pretty/pretty-0.1.tar.gz) and unpack the `pretty.py` file.
2. Run 2to3 on it:

   ```
   python -m lib2to3 -w pretty.py
   ```
3. Comment out the following lines:

   ```
   569: types.DictProxyType:        _dict_pprinter_factory('<dictproxy {', '}>'),
   580: xrange:                     _repr_pprint,
   ```
4. Put the file near your script.
5. Import it as usual:

   ```
   import pretty
   ```

Comment: @Equidamoid: have you succeeded?

Comment: However, `pretty` doesn't like numpy.ndarray =(

Answer (score 1):

for pretty printing you may be looking for `__str__` instead of (or as well as) `__repr__`

e.g.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print now
2013-05-19 13:00:34.085383
>>> print repr(now)
datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 19, 13, 0, 34, 85383)
```

Comment: Now imagine that instead of datetime you have a class with several `dict`s big enough so they don't fit into one terminal row. And then you have a `dict` with several those objects... That's my case.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generic solution that prints the contents of object fields by subclassing PrettyPrinter.
`obj.__dict__` will give you a dictionary of all fields of `obj`.

Or you can just use `obj.__class__.__name__ + pformat(obj.__dict__)`.